# $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ normalizes $K$. Is $H/K$ a group?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I don't see any problem defining a group in this manner. 
$(aK)(bK):=(ab)K$. Let $ak_1$ and $bk_2$ be elements from $aK$ and $bK$. Then $ak_1bk_2=abk_3k_2$ since $H$ normalizes $K$. So the operation is well-defined. That it is a group follows from the fact that $H$ is a group.

Comment: The fact is that $aK$ is not necessarily a coset of $K$ in $H$. What you are looking at is actually $HK/K$.

Comment: What definition of "$H$ _normalizes_ $K$" are you using? Do you mean that $K\lhd\langle H,K\rangle$, i.e., $K$ is normal in the span of $H,K$ ?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas for all $h$ in $H$, $hKh^{-1}=K$

Comment: @ancientmathematician why do we need cosets of $K$ in $H$? Why not $G$?

Comment: Because that's what $H/K$ **means**. You are talking about the cosets of $K$ in the group $HK$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician okay. Let's not write it as $H/K$. Let's call it something else. Is that something else not a group?

Comment: Yes, I keep saying it is $HK/K$.

Comment: Why are people querying what "$H$ normalizes $K$" means? It means $H \le N_G(K)$,

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh so the group I'm describing is $HK/K$

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ normalizes $K$, that means $H \subseteq N_G(K)$, which does not imply $K \subseteq H$. So $H/K$ has no meaning in general. You can construct a counterexample finding a group $G$ with $H=Z(G)$ non-trivial and $K \nsubseteq Z(G)$ for some subgroup $K$. $D_4$, the dihedral of $8$ elements, would work here...

Comment: What's the harm if $K$ is not a subset of $H$?

Comment: Then $H/K$ does not have any meaning.